# Cant run instrumentation with InstrumentationRunListener

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

I am trying to run android instrumentation tests with a custom run listener

Here is my listener
this class resides in the folder `app/src/androidTest/java/com/app/myapp`

```
class AnnotationTestListener : InstrumentationRunListener() {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun testStarted(description: Description) {
        super.testStarted(description)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        instrumentation.sendStatus(InstrumentationResultPrinter.REPORT_VALUE_RESULT_START, bundle)
    }

}
```

then I am trying to invoke the instrumentation listener the following way

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e log true -e listener com.app.myapp.AnnotationTestListener com.app.myapp.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner | tee -a listeners/test.txt
```

but the result is

```
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

`adb shell pm list instrumentation` yields

```
instrumentation:androidx.test.orchestrator/.AndroidTestOrchestrator (target=androidx.test.orchestrator)
instrumentation:com.app.myapp.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner (target=com.app.myapp)
```

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that the device was locked.

It's not intuitive but the error message of this are also printed in the error logcat.